# Sum of Non Unique elements to N

Tags: java

I was asked a question in an interview.Let's say we have an array on integers {1,2,3}, find the numbers that sum to 10? Numbers could be repeated:
For example sample response would give 
{2,2,2,2,2}
or
{7,3}
or 
{3,3,2,2};

Any algorithm would help.No code required.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929938/subset-sum-algorithm-with-repetition-of-numbers-in-the-set

Comment: Do you need to store/display all the solutions or simply to count it.

Comment: store it in an arraylist