# How to add the same element N times?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,6]
list2 = []
```

And i have a number: N

How can I append the numbers of list1 to list2 so that the sum of the list2 is equal to N.

Exemple:

```
n = 10
list2 = [2,2,6]
```

I could not find a way to add the 2 until the sum equal to 10

Comment: sounds like a dynamic programming problem

Comment: What happens when you aren't able to reach the value of N?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subset sum algorithm with repetition of numbers in the set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929938/subset-sum-algorithm-with-repetition-of-numbers-in-the-set)

Comment: It will always be possible once there is an element greater than 0

Comment: @taynan No, it wouldn't. If 1 is in the set then of course it would be possible, but if e.g. all of the numbers were even and the target number is odd, then it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
list1 = [1,2,6]
list2 = []
n = 10

list1 = sorted(list1, reverse=True) # sort list descending order

for i in list1:                     # for each item in list1
    list2.append(i)                 # add the item to list2
    while not sum(list2) >  n:      # while sum of list2 is less than n 
        list2.append(i)             # keep adding the same element
    if sum(list2) > n:              # if sum of list2 is more than n
        list2.pop()                 # remove the last element added

list2.sort() # sort list ascending order
print(list2) # [2, 2, 6]
```

Works for the given `list1`.

Might need to test on different length and numbers of `list1`.

Comment: Wow, that's awsome man, it's working. I had tried to do something similar, but instead "while not sum(list2) > n:", i tried "while sum(list2) <=n:", but for some reason it was not working :(
Really thanks man

Comment: yeah you could probably do the same with "while sum(list2) <=n:" and change a few other things. glad to help. if you feel this answered your question, please consider upvoting or accepting it, thanks.

Comment: reverse the list really was a great idea O.O